# SharePoint 2010 to 2019 Upgrade

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, upgrade, 2019

we have a SharePoint 2010 farm now we want to upgrade to the new version SharePoint 2019, for SharePoint 2010 to 2019 what are Upgrade steps?

1. Can i first upgrade to SharePoint 2013 and after SharePoint 2019
   directly?
2. Upgrade to SharePoint 2013 and after SharePoint 2016 and SharePoint
   2019?

we have data around 8 TB and is SharePoint 2019 is stable to use in Production Farms in a Large EnterPrise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going the database-attach route, the steps are as follows:

1. Attach databases to a SharePoint 2013 Web Application; upgrade to Windows Claims authentication (if running Windows Classic) using `Convert-SPWebApplication https://webAppUrl -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissions:$true
2. On SharePoint 2013, upgrade all sites from v14.5 to v15 mode using `Upgrade-SPSite`.
3. Attach the databases to a SharePoint 2016 farm which will upgrade them.
4. Attach the databases to a SharePoint 2019 farm which will upgrade them.

While there isn't an article to address Step #1, here is a useful article: [High level overview to upgrade from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-from-sharepoint2013-to-sharepointserver-2019).

Comment: Thanks, Trevor for your answer, IS SharePoint 2016 supports Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise Edition?

Answer (score 2):

1st thing, yes it is stable and use for production environment. You will get modern interface experience.

For migration, there is no direct-way from 2010 to 2019. you have to go step by step. like this: 2010 to 2013 to 2016 to 2019.

other option is use the 3rd party tools to migrate the directly from 2010 to 2013. Their are advantage of using the 3rd party tools when you skip too many versions.

Comment: Note there is no support to go from 'classic' site templates to Modern Team sites. You would need to use a content migration tool (e.g. Sharegate) to migrate content from a classic site to Modern site.